# Successful performance update to web app, but don't know why. How to find out?

Tags: performance, zend-framework, optimization, jmeter

this is kind of a strange title, so let me explain:

We have a web application (PHP, Zend Framework) that is quite successfull. Over time traffic grew and performance degraded (tens of requests with 80ms to tenthousands requests with >600ms average). We didn't expect so much traffic when first designing the application, so no big surprise. We decided to look into many things that could improve the performance.

After some days into the effort a production bug appeared that needed to be fixed. As the first changes we made to clean up some queries and caching code were already done and tested, we figured we could just add these to the update. None of the changes really improved the performance much in local testing and staging, but anyway.

But yeah, it did on production. Our graphes plunged to almost zero and we were totally destroyed that the update somehow made all the traffic disappear. But as we looked closer, the graphs were back to 80ms and almost invisible next to the 600ms mountains ;)

So we totally fixed the performance problems with some changes, we didn't even think would make a difference. Total success, but of course we want to understand which of these changes made the difference.

How would you tackle this problem?

Some background:

- PHP application using Zend Framework, MySQL as database, Memcache for caching.
- We get our performance graphs and insight into the application from NewRelic.com, but I can't really find the reason of the better performance there.
- Using jMeter we could reproduce the bad performance on our dev servers, and also more or less the better performance of the updated version.

The only idea I have right now is to start with the old version, loadtest it, add one commit, loadtest it, add another feature, loadtest it... but this doesn't sound any fun or very effective.

---

**Update:** We found the reason for the performance problems, I will add an answer later to explain what we did and what the reason was. (Or how are updates and solutions handled to such questions?)

---

**Update 2:** Will add solution and way to find it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what was the problem? Two additional ' in a MySQL query. They number value going into the method accidentally was a string, so the ORM used ' around it. Normally these problems are caught by the optimizer, but in this case it was a quite complicated combination of JOINs, perhaps that's why it was missed. Because this was also the most used query, every execution of it was a tiny bit slower - but that made all the difference in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use XDebug or Zend Studio to debug your application.

Running it through the profiler will show you a breakdown of the execution flow, and all methods called, how long they took, and how much memory you used.  The profiler should reveal if some block of code is called many times, or if there is something that simply takes a long time to execute sometimes.

If you do see 20ish millisecond responses from the profiler, then I would run a load tester in the background while I profiled on a different machine to see if heavy load seems to explain some of the time increases, and if so, what exactly is taking longer.

To me, that is the easiest way to see what is taking so long rather than loading different version of code and seeing how long they take.  Doing it that way, you at least know which branch had the speed problem, but then you are still left to hunt down why it is taking so long as it may not be as simple as some piece of code being changed or optimized.  It could be a combination of things.

I use Zend Studio for profiling and it is a huge time saver with that feature.  XDebug's profiler is very similar AFIK.

Docs:
http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/profiling.htm
http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: Profiling is on of the obvious answers, problem is we don't really know which requests are faster - according to our rendering time stats all of them are! So I don't this will help after the fact.

Comment: I would put back one of the older revisions that had some slow requests to see if you could identify what was taking so long sometimes.  Btw, is the graph time only timing how long it took PHP to execute or is that counting round trip time to some server?  I was wondering if maybe you were hitting a bottleneck in the network or something.

Comment: We looked at the older revisions, but of course there were many, many bad things. And even in the much better version, there are so many horrible things. So that's a search for the needle in the haystack :(

We have several metrics in place, one is application render time (php + mysql + memcache), another enduser monitoring (network time and such) and of course monitoring of all the server components (mem, cpu, disk and network). Nothing is indicative to why it is so much faster now.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you need to profile the old version of the app and the new version of the app with the same realistic data but I somehow doubt you're going to have the time or inclination to do that.

What you could do is start by comparing the efficiency of the DB queries you've re-written against the previous versions, also look at how often they're called etc., and what effect the caching you've introduced has on that.

What I would also do is change the process going forward so that you introduce change as a flow (continuous integration/deployment style) so that you can see the impact of individual changes more clearly.

Comment: Profiling the 2 version against each other is exactly what we did, and I'm happy to anounce that we found the culprit. Will update my main post as soon as possible. Just checking query performance and count was not really an option, as it only happened under huge load and was not really visible on individual queries. That's also the reason why our continuous integration server didn't help a bit: I found no way to add a read load test to the test cycle without making it need 20 minutes and needing to much hardware, bandwidth and developer attention.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply cannot optimize and locally scale any more, take a look here:

http://www.zend.com/en/products/php-cloud/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but actually scaling is no problem at all. See, we even did it by accident :P Our problem is sometimes, understanding which of the many changes triggered the better performance.